# Ruby how to send data to input on other page and get result to my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, get, net-http

In my Ruby on Rails application i need to send get request to another web page, after that on that page will be redirect and all search result's will be visible... But how can i do this in rails? I simple need send get-request and get to my app values of elements, which are in specific css id or class, also it will be array...

With first part i think it is good to use net::http, but how to solve second part of question?

Comment: @GBD  no, it doesn't return... but i must to do somethink like this.  Also es simple exampe i can tell: in ruby i send to google search request... it doesn't send anything to me, but i must collect to my app search result's that it gives... it's only example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) for web scraping purposes. It uses Nokogiri for parsing pages.